# Moving the hint of EditText to top in Android Java

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

How to move the hint of EditText (Android Java) to the top of the view while typing?
I have attached 2 images to show how I want to implement my EditText View.

[image] ***To*** [image]

How to make **`search country`** hint at the top of view as per the image?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout) you can achieve this.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchCountriesInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/searchCountriesEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search Countries" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: @RaghavAmbashta: Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried but It showed an error.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: The app just gets crashed every time

Comment: Ok, please post the logcat content to see what's wrong.

Comment: 2020-08-05 13:48:42.183 7727-7727/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 7727
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)

Comment: I got the solution. I had to update theme in my @style to Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Thank You

Comment: Good, You're welcome, I'm happy to see the problem is resolved :)

Comment: sure..I ll do it

Answer (score 1):

You can user TextInputLayout for this :-

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilSearchCountry"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_normal"
        android:hint="@string/your_hint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearchCountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In case if you haven't included google material library add this in your `build.gradle:`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: What is @+id/tvHeader ?

Comment: Sorry @RaghavAmbashta that was my fault i was trying to use this in one of my layout in order to provide you the solution and ended up with that tag i have updated the answer

Comment: Also need to update @style theme to Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar and android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_normal" shows error

Comment: padding_normal is just a standard padding that you might have defined in your dimens.xml if not just use 16dp instead or according to your requirement that's just standard naming conventions for padding in application don't get confused with it use padding according to your requirement.